# ProCurve 2610 Java error?

Tags: java, switch, hp-procurve

I've got two identical procurve 2610-24/12PWR switches with the web interface configured.  I can log in to one and see all the management info just fine.  When I load the web interface of the other I'm asked to authenticate as usual and the various java applets that comprise the page start to load.  Then they all fail concurrently and generate a pile of ClassNotFoundExceptions in the java console.

What gives?  The switch appears to be operating normally otherwise.

Comment: Have you rebooted the switch recently? This happend to me and the web server had locked up.

Comment: I haven't rebooted it, no.  The other switch shows uptime of 213 days so I presume this one is the same.  The management interface was working last week...  unfortunately unless these java applets load I can't even reboot remotely - catch 22!

Comment: Did you enable the telnet interface? In fact I think It's on by default

Comment: You're right, I can telnet in.  I'm a little hesitant to reboot now though, just in case it doesn't come back up cleanly...

Comment: I've resolved to wait until that site closes then issue a reload via telnet.

Comment: if that works via Telnet please comment and I will put my comments into an anwser for you to accpect :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I rebooted the switch to no avail.  I'm going to have to wait for a good time to update firmware, but it's really strange to have something like this fail out of the blue.

Answer (score 3):

What operating system, web browser, JRE and firmware version are you using?

We have dozens of 2600 series switches and we haven't seen any issues with the Java applets embedded in their web interface. For the records we're using R.11_72 firmware on our switches and the web interface works fine in Firefox 10.0.2 with Java 1.6.0_27.

I would try upgrading to the most recent firmware available for your switches (probably R.11.72) and make sure your web browser and Java is updated and configured appropriately. Have you tried using different browsers?

If all this fails, you should take advantage of ProCurve's free lifetime support and call HP.

Lastly, unless you have specifically disabled it you should still be able to manage your switches via the console.

Comment: win2k3 sp2, chrome 17.0.963.56, java 1.6.0_31, firmware R.11.30.

Comment: Also, the other switch (same exact configuration on all accounts) works fine.  The java applets on this one are just borked.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Yep, same error in IE.